# How to add event to an image when insert it from link in javascript?

Tags: javascript

First, I have an image exist in my html, I add dblclick event to toggle class in windown.onload and it work OK.

//html

```
<button onclick="insertImageImageFromLink('../pic02.png')" >
 Add New Image
</button>
<div contenteditable="true">
<img src="../pic01.png" />
</div>
```

//css

```
button{
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}
img {
border:5px solid white;
}
.ontap-2{border-color:green;}
```

//javascript

```
function toggleClass(elem, name) {
    if (elem.className.indexOf(name) < 0) {
        elem.className += ' '+name;
    } else {
        elem.className = elem.className.split(name).join('');
    }
}

function clearSelection() {
    var selection =
        window.getSelection ? window.getSelection() :
        document.getSelection ? document.getSelection() :
        document.selection;

    if (selection && selection.removeAllRanges) {
        // W3C-style
        selection.removeAllRanges();

    } else if (selection && selection.empty) {
        // IE-style
        selection.empty();
    }
}

function setupEventForAnImage(image) {
    image.ondblclick=function(){
    toggleClass(image,'ontap-2');
    clearSelection();
    };
}
function prepareEventHandlers() {      
   var imageArray = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
  for (var i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++) {
    var image = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[i];
    setupEventForAnImage(image);
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    // prep anything we need to
    prepareEventHandlers();
};
```

Now, I need to add image to contenteditable div from a button

```
<button onclick="insertImageImageFromLink('../pic02.png')" >

function insertNodeAtCursor(node) {
    var range, html;
    if (window.getSelection && window.getSelection().getRangeAt) {
        range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        range.insertNode(node);
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        html = (node.nodeType == 3) ? node.data : node.outerHTML;
        range.pasteHTML(html);
    }
}

function insertImageImageFromLink(imageLink){
    var imge = new Image();
    imge.src = imageLink;
    insertNodeAtCursor(imge);
    setupEventForAnImage(image);
}
```

**Insert image work on my browser, but setupEventForAnImage(image); not work**
Some thing like this code : http://jsfiddle.net/DSa7a/4/ but function insert image only work in my browser, not work on this link.

**How to add event to image if insert it from a link?**

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: I think there is a typo mate, in `insertImageImageFromLink`, shouldn't it be `setupEventForAnImage(imge);`?

Comment: This call from onload for exist image, it work. Same function when insert new image.

Comment: Also, if you are doing so much DOM magic, then you should really look into libraries like jQuery. They make DOM managing code much much cleaner and easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/SRBQ6/). The event seems to be working fine.

There just seems to be a typo in the original code. In the `insertImageImageFromLink` function, it should be

`setupEventForAnImage(imge);`

instead of

`setupEventForAnImage(image);`

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, it's my fault!